# Quick way of mapping a stored procedure in C# EF (using Database.SqlQuery)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following in a using statement:

```
var result = await db.Database.SqlQuery<ModelLookup>("EXEC prGetModel", new {ManufacturerId = manufacturerId}).ToListAsync();
```

And a `ModelLookup` class :

```
public class ModelLookup
{
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public string ModelDesc { get; set; }
}
```

Some of the DB columns have a different name.

Is there a quick way (or data annotation) that I can use to take a column from the database and map to the desired field?

(without having to add the procedure to a `DbContext`)

Thanks,

Comment: can't you return form your Stored Procedure columns with name same as properties?

Comment: That would be lovely but, the naming conventions between the DB and the code are different and I would incur the wrath of the DBA.

Comment: i do return names same as my model properties so they can be mapped easily

Comment: `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column(Name="SPColumnName")]`

Comment: Thanks for your  replies folks!

I'm pretty sure I tried that annotation Codecaster.

I may just have to modify the proc.

Comment: If it doesn't work, show how you used it. Perhaps there's a different solution, or chances are you did something wrong. :) (use @Username to notify someone of your reply)

Comment: I'll give it another try to make sure :)